# Scoping 'this' within a reactjs component

Tags: reactjs, this

While building my first reactjs component, I got the familiar "undefined is not a function" when trying to use a helper (`makeWorkSiteUrl`) because the `this` scope had changed away from being that of the component.

Of course, I just did what most JS developers would do and declared `that=this` before I made my function call to solve the problem.

However, it occurred to me that this is probably a common problem. So there might be a 'better' or 'react' way of achieving the same thing.  Or, it may be an indication of poor design of this component.  Is there a style or method that is preferred or available instead of `that=this` to access a components internal functions/properties?

"Undefined is not a function":

```
var WorkSiteQuickList = React.createClass({
    propTypes: {
        data: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired     
    },
    render() {
        var workSiteNodes = this.props.data.work_sites.map(function (worksite) {
            var linkUrl = this.makeWorkSiteUrl(worksite.id) //Fail  
            return (
                <WorkSiteQuickListItem workSiteName={worksite.name} linkUrl={linkUrl} />
            );
        });
        return (
                <div>    
                    {workSiteNodes}             
               </div>
        );
    },
    makeWorkSiteUrl(workSiteId) {
        return "/worksite/"+ workSiteId;
    }   
});
```

Works as expected:

```
var WorkSiteQuickList = React.createClass({
    propTypes: {
        data: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired     
    },
    render() {
        that = this;
        var workSiteNodes = this.props.data.work_sites.map(function (worksite) {
            var linkUrl = that.makeWorkSiteUrl(worksite.id) //OK  
            return (
                <WorkSiteQuickListItem workSiteName={worksite.name} linkUrl={linkUrl} />
            );
        });
        return (
                <div>    
                    {workSiteNodes}             
               </div>
        );
    },
    makeWorkSiteUrl(workSiteId) {
        return "/worksite/"+ workSiteId;
    }   
});
```

I'm sure this question will be closed, but I'd rather ask it than miss a critical part of the "framework".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some common patterns to deal with `this` scoping:

- Utilizing an es6 transpiler (like the JSX transformer that you're currently using, or babeljs which happens to support JSX), use arrow functions which are scoped to the outer context (aka *lexical scoping*).

  ```
   this.props.data.work_sites.map( (worksite) => { .... return ... } )
  ```
- Pass in `this` as the second argument of [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- Chain bind onto the function you pass into `Array#map`

  ```
  function() {}.bind(this)
  ```

---

Update: I've had a lot of trouble lately with `=>`, `this` resolving to `window` when paused at a breakpoint in the *chrome dev tools* within the `render()` method. Originally I thought it was a babeljs bug. However, turns out it's actually a failure of the dev tools ability to understand that source maps actually replace `this` with `_this`.

Comment: Awesome!  Great, great answer.  I love the es6 arrow functions thing.  That is super useful.

Comment: I used the arrow function to great effect here.  I'm glad I asked this question because it is clearly the ideal way to handle these situations in JSX (and es6).

Comment: I agree it's the best way. I re-arranged the list so it appears 1st.